# Entity Framework 6 specific column mapping

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

In SQL, I would tell the database what the foreign key constraint is.

But fluent EF6 apparently does not have a way for me to specify what column to use when binding collections.

Is it not possible to tell DbModelBuilder exactly what column to bind relationships on? Or does it demand to be the primary key at all times?

Table_Person

`id          int // pkey. Multiple people records
UniqueID    int // the unique person
sometext    varchar(256) // database therefore tracks changes to this, since unique person can have many records (pkeys).`

Table_Address

`id          int   //pkey
fk_unique   int   // should map to UniqueID of person, NOT the pkey.
line1       varchar(512)
state       varchar(64)
etc`

One unique person has many records, and their uniqueID (not pkey) has many associated addresses. Actual structure is far more complex than that. But am looking for a way to do this fundamentally...

Would very much so like to have an `ICollection<Address> Addresses` within the `Persons` model. But to enable such a thing for code-first migrations... seems impossible?
Yes I could `Add-Migration` and then modify the generated code/sql manually. But doesn't that defeat the point? Or is that common practice?

Comment: EF versions before Core support only FK relationships referring to the PK of the principal *entity*. I don't recommend you modifying the database schema manually (thus lying EF) because EF will just stop working correctly with the relationship. What you can do though is to map the `UniqueID` as PK of the entity (it doesn't really matter that it isn't in the db, as soon as it's unique and non nullable).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're able to modify the DB schema you could put UniqueIDs for people into their own table named "Person" and rename the existing table to "PersonVersion". Then have FKs to the new "Person" table on "PersonVersion" and "Address". And finally, create the Person, PersonVersion, and Address models in your app code and EF should bind without problem.